# Django: Can't update database properly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='Title')
    post = models.TextField(verbose_name='Post')
    post_time = models.DateTimeField()
    update_time = models.DateTimeField()
    exists = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.post_time = timezone.now()
            # self.exists = True
        self.update_time = timezone.now()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class PostEditHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()
    edit_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_post(request, username, post_id):
    other_user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    post = Post.objects.get(user=other_user.pk, pk=post_id)
    prev_post = post

    form = EditPostForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        PostEditHistory.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            post=prev_post,
            title=prev_post.title,
            body=prev_post.post,
            edit_time=prev_post.update_time
        )
        return redirect('single_post', username=username, post_id=post_id)
        form.save()


    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog_post/edit_post.html', context)
```

Before saving edited post, I'm trying to save the original post to `PostEditHistory` model. Every time a post is edited, it performs the same operations. But the code save the edited post to both `Post` and `PostEditHistory` model, and the original one gets lost. Help me to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Added some suggestions @Shakir maybe it help you improve your code

Comment: you dont have a "previous" nor an "edited" post here, it's the very same post under two names. And what you store in your history is only a foreign key, not the state of the post before it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving of your function before use form.save()

```
 return redirect('single_post', username=username, post_id=post_id)
 form.save()
```

Change the position

```
 form.save()
 return redirect('single_post', username=username, post_id=post_id)
```

**Suggestion:** You should remove logic from views and handle it only in your models using functions...

Obs.: *Dont use straight .objects.get() because if this do not exist will break your page and throw error, use filter to get the values without breaking and check it*

```
class PostHistory(models.Model):
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def add_history(user, prev_post):
        PostEditHistory.objects.create(
            user=user,
            post=prev_post,
            title=prev_post.title,
            body=prev_post.post,
            edit_time=prev_post.update_time
        )

@login_required
def edit_post(request, username, post_id):
    ...
    post = Post.objects.filter(user=other_user.pk, pk=post_id).first()
    prev_post = post if post else None
    if form.is_valid():
        PostEditHistory.add_history(request.user, prev_post)
        form.save()

        return redirect('single_post', username=username, post_id=post_id)
```

Comment: I've replaced my logic with yours, but it acts same as mine. I find no difference.

Comment: My Suggestions will not give you any different... but will follow some basic rules using MVC

Comment: Yo first your problem you should follow the steps i said in beggining of post changing the return after the save form